# Displaying hebrew characters with SQL collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2

Tags: sql-server, collation, hebrew

We have a remote database that is out of our control.
The database contains Hebrew characters. It's collation is: SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2

When we open the SQL management studio - we see gibberish.

We asked the database owner (a different company) to change the collation and it isn't possible.

Is there an alternative way to see Hebrew characters with this collation setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collation is not about displaying characters, but about sorting and comparing.

Make sure you have a Hebrew font installed on your client PC, and assign this font under Tools/Options/Environment/Fonts and Colors.